# Rescan all Photos in Photos Library

Tags: photos.app

I'm having trouble with the face recognition on my Mac (Ventura 13.2.1). In the new photos it runs a really good face recognition algorithm and new photos are quickly analyzed. But it only covers new photos. Is there any possibility (incl. manually changing the SQlite database()) to force photos to start a new analysis on alle pictures. I don't want to reimport my pictures, the library is already 16 years old and started unter iPhoto.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

### Unfortunately not

Photos app will only scan photos for people once, at the first opening of the Photos app or when a new photo is added (it will scan the added photo). This is from [Find and identify photos of people in Photos on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/photos/phtad9d981ab/mac) :

> When you ***first open Photos***, it scans your library to identify people in your photos. **After the scan is done**, you can open the People album, view photos organised by the faces in them, and assign names to the people Photos found.

But, you can still create people manually (I reckon this might be tiresome since you must have quite a lot of photos after 16 years). For this, go to the People album and, at the bottom of this "page", click on the "Add +" button, this will let you select recognized photos (with people on it), name them and eventually add them to the People album.

Comment: The problem is that the people section itself seems to be corrupt. The number of photos when selected a person, is much too small and also when searching for additional photos where this person might be, it never finishes searching plus some other strange behaviour. Do you know where photoanalysisd is saving the information which photos it alredy scanned? In photos.sqlite I haven’t found any table which holds this information

Comment: @Tretsche This is the plist file used to manage the contents of your Photo Library, the People folder should be there : `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.photoanalysisd/caches/graph/PhotoAnalysisServiceFeaturesAnalytics.plist`. ⚠️ Do not modify anything here!

Comment: @Tretsche What is the strange behaviour you're talking about?

Comment: 1) When I give faces new names, these names are not present in the People-View. But when I use smart albums to search photos with the new name, it finds the photos.

Comment: 2) when merging persons, all the thumbnails of the other persons disappear and when i try to merge another person, it will use two persons which i didn’t select. 
I decided to start fresh and to use PowerPhotos to copy all the photos to a new library including all other metadata but faces. I started with 1600 photos, but photoanalysisd still hasn’t analyzed any of them. I set the new library as system, is it enough to tell photoanalysisd which shall be scanned?